# How to create new shortcuts on kile?

Tags: kile

The shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> inserts `\left(  \right)` within the text.

How to create new shortcuts in Kile to insert other delimiters, such as `[] {}`?

Comment: Presumably you know you can assign shortcut key combinations to `\left[`, `\right]`, ... individually through the usual `kile` assign shortcuts mechanism?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the German community [UbuntuUsers](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de) a similar question was answered. Here the original Question: [*Kile: eigene Shortcuts definieren?*](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kile%3a-eigene-shortcuts-definieren/)

So I answer this question in relation to the linked post. I tested my answer with *Kile 2.1 beta 4*

1. Open Kile
2. go to: *LaTeX* -> *User-Tags* -> *Edit User Tags*
3. Add your own user tag.

If these settings are lost after a restart, use the following guideline:

First add a new shortcut to your own *kilerc*:

1. Open the file kilerc

   ```
   gedit $HOME/.kde/share/config/kilerc
   ```

   I use `gedit` in Ubuntu, but you can use a different editor if you want.
2. Search for the following string in the open *kilerc*: `[User]`
3. Under `[User]` add the following lines:

   ```
   nUserTags=1
   userTag0={%C}
   userTagName0=bracket`
   ```
4. Open *Kile* and go to

   *Settings* -> *Configure Shortcuts*
5. Search for *bracket* and set the shortcut.

**EDIT**
Today I found the correct documentation

[User-Defined Tags](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/latex_usertags.html)

Comment: Thank Marco. And cursor between {and}? equal to $ $ where the cursor is in the middle.

Comment: Might I repeat the question of Regis da Silva: How does one ensure that the cursor is in between the braces? I am trying to get \enquote{} to work like \textit{} from the toolbar so that one could select text and have it italicized. I want to do the same with \enquote{}. Simply defining it as a user tag and adding does not seem to plant the cursor between the braces. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: @chandra: *%C: this is where the cursor will be placed after the insertion of a user-defined tag.*

Comment: Thank you, Marco. I have done that and now get a blinking cursor between the braces. That is OK when I want to insert text after invoking \enquote. But I am still unable to replicate the behaviour of \textit{} which grabs the selected text and puts it between the braces when \textit{} is invoked *after* the text has been typed. With user tags, does it have to do with `Add` versus `Insert`? I tried both but cannot find any difference.

Comment: @chandra: Now I understand you problem. I have to test it.

Comment: Oops! I have just seen your link to the docs. I have amended my entry to \\enquote{%M%C} and it now works as desired! Thank you very much.

Comment: And here is a generic shortcut for any simple macro with one argument: `\%C{%M}`. My purpose is that I can write the text without formatting, then I read it again, select words/parts, then apply the schortcut and write down the exact macro to apply to it. (In inline linguistic examples with `textglos`, there's at least `\xv{} \xo{} \xt{} \xm{} \gl{}` and I defined quite a few others... that I really use a lot and all at the same time. It would be too much shortcuts to set and remember.)