# Is it possible to add a shortcut that activates a script in Kile editor?

Tags: editors, kile, build-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create new shortcuts on kile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27295/how-to-create-new-shortcuts-on-kile)

I am using Kile in Ubuntu 11.04. I have a script that is used frequently when I compile my TeX files. I wish that I could add a short cut, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, that could activate that script. Does anyone know whether this is possible or not? I have tried to add new command in `Configure Kile` -> `Tools` -> `Build`. But I failed to get what I want.

Comment: @Marco: Does the linked post pertain to scripts, or merely in-editor replacements?

Comment: @Werner: The procedure is the same. Every script which is defined in Kile can get shortcut (see link point 4).

Comment: Thanks Marco. I want to use a shortcut to run a shell script. It seems not exactly the same as your link. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Werner: Please see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In relation to the comments I want to show how a shell script can be insert in [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/):

For the explanation we take a simple shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
pdflatex $@
```

In our example we call it `shellexample`. Now the shell script must be executable with [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html):

```
chmod a+x shellexample
```

To use the shell script we must copy the script to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo cp shellexample /usr/local/bin
```

Now we can run our script from every point.

Now we start [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/). In the toolbar we go to *Setting* -> *Configure Kile*. In the new window we choose in the left sidebar under *Tools* -> *Build*.

Now we can add a new tool. We push the button <kbd>New...</kbd> and follow the coming introduction:

1. Toolname (in our example: *`shellscriptinkile`*)
2. Class (in our case we need no class)

The new tool is finished. In the selected tool we add the name of our shell script in the  <kbd>command</kbd> field : `shellexample`. Now we can close the Window because Kile now know our script.

At this point Kile has no shortcut for our script. To define a shortcut:

1. go to: *Settings* -> *Configure Shortcuts*
2. In the new open window we search in the <kbd>Search</kbd>-field our defined toolname: *`shellscriptinkile`*
3. set the shortcut :D

To get some inspiration how to define a new tool you can look at the tools `pdflatex`, `makeindex` and so on.

Comment: You reference your script as `shellexample` at the beginning. Should this have been `shellscriptinkile` as you use this later?

Comment: @Werner: `shellscriptinkile` is only the name of the tool in Kile. The script itself is called `shellexample`.

Comment: Thanks Marco Daniel, it works well. by the way, you can pass parameters like '%S' (the file name) to the script.:-)