# How do I automatically generate BibTeX citation template in Kile?

Tags: bibtex, citing, automation, kile

When I want to cite something in BibTeX, I Google (for example) *bibtex article* and scour [for pages with example templates](https://verbosus.com/bibtex-style-examples.html) filled out:

```
@article{article,
  author  = {Peter Adams}, 
  title   = {The title of the work},
  journal = {The name of the journal},
  year    = 1993,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = {201-213},
  month   = 7,
  note    = {An optional note}, 
  volume  = 4
}
```

I then copy/paste it into Kile and delete the fields I don't need.

Surely Kile has a better way to do this built in.  I tried <kbd>LaTeX</kbd>⟶<kbd>Bibliography</kbd>⟶<kbd>Article in Journal</kbd> but that pastes the following in my document:

```
@Article{,
 author = {},
 title = {},
 journal = {},
 year = {},
 OPTkey = {},
 OPTvolume = {},
 OPTnumber = {},
 OPTpages = {},
 OPTmonth = {},
 OPTnote = {},
 OPTannote = {},
 OPTurl = {},
 OPTurldate = {},
 OPTlastchecked = {},
 OPTdoi = {},
 OPTisbn = {},
 OPTissn = {},
 OPTlocalfile = {},
 OPTabstract = {},
 OPTkeywords = {},
}
```

which is close but different from what I am after.

Is there a way for Kile to write BibTeX citation templates like the ones linked above in my document?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but shouldn't kile provide a menu for bibliographies in which you could customize the layout for bib-entries?

Comment: @Naphaneal, One would think, but it isn't in any of the usual <kbd>Settings</kbd>⟶<kbd>Configure Kile</kbd> places.

Comment: I think you want to create a `snippet`. The easiest way is probably to create the template you want in a document i.e. just how you'd like Kile to produce it. Then highlight it and go to Tools -> Create Snippet and configure as desired. You can also go to Tools -> Snippets to manage them without highlighting stuff, but I think it is easiest for a new snippet to set it out just how you'd like it in source so you know the format is the way you want it.

Comment: @cfr, thanks for the tip. I'll give it a shot next time I'm at work.

Comment: Do have a look. I think `template` in Kile's terms has to be for a new document, which I don't think is what you want here unless you have one `.bib` per entry ;). But a `snippet` should work, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old. Maybe you have already found some workaround but one that is working nowadays with Kile (version 2.9.93) is to use *User Menus*, as what was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27391/117801) (noticing that user menus were called user tags at that time). You can find them in the menu here:

```
LaTeX -> Edit User Menu
```

or there:

```
Wizard -> Edit User Menu
```

depending on [your configuration settings](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kile/kile/id_usermenu.html).

Comment: I use Kile and there is no 'User-Tags' option in the LaTeX menu.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, this is now (version 2.9.93, a.k.a. "3.0 Beta 3") called a "User Menu", accessible through `LaTeX -> Edit User Menu`; at least, this is so for my Debian Testing system. If you confirm, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have `Wizard -> Edit User Menu` and I also have Kile 2.9.93. I'm using Arch. I'm certain Arch won't have changed it. I also kind of doubt Debian would. It would be a weird thing to change. Maybe the location depends on configuration somehow?

Comment: Well spotted! Neither Arch or Debian people did anything to Kile on that matter. Our differences actually come from a configuration setting in `Settings -> Configure Kile -> Kile -> User Menu -> Location`. Some screenshots are available in [the official documentation](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kile/kile/id_usermenu.html) and make it all cristal clear. As a consequence, I'm going to edit my answer.