# How to create shortcuts on kile since user-tags are missing?

Tags: kile, shortcut

As described in this old thread: [How to create new shortcuts on kile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27295/how-to-create-new-shortcuts-on-kile), user-defined syntax shortcuts in `kile`, e.g. to create a `footcite`-command swiftly, until now were defined in the menu under LaTex > User Tags.

But this submenu has been removed in my version of `kile`(2.9.91)/`kate`(17.12.3).

I have found no comment on this change in the `kile` documention. Has anybody a suggestion on how to restore this funtionality in `kile`?

Comment: I opened a bug on this (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393322). No reaction so far.

Comment: I closed the bug, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been replaced by Latex > User Menu where you can easily define shortcuts like the "User Tags" of earlier versions of kile. You can even import the older "User Tag" settings with one click in the "Edit User Menu" dialog. At least in the documentation of kile-2.9.92 this has been explained perfectly.